# how to set path when applying single puppet module?

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to run a single module like this:

```
puppet apply --verbose --modulepath=moduleshere --noop -e 'include myclass'
```

However, I get this kind of error, indicating the path is not set

```
Parameter unless failed: '[ -e "${logfile}" ]' is not qualified and no path was specified. Please qualify the command or specify a path.
```

I don't want to explicitly specify the path in every such location, and it works fine when run as part of a full puppet run.  How can I specify the path when running a single module?

Comment: Could you please accept the appropriate answer?

Answer (score 16):

The commands in an `Exec` resource either have to be fully qualified (i. e. `/usr/bin/test` instead of `test`) or the `path` attribute of that `Exec` resource has to be set.

If you can modify the Puppet manifest(s) you can simply add the following definition for setting a default `path` attribute for all `Exec` resources to `/bin`:

```
Exec { path => "/bin" }
```

As a (more or less) dirty workaround you can also just set the default `path` for any `Exec` resource on the command line:

```
$ puppet apply --verbose -e 'Exec { path => "/bin" }' your_manifest.pp
```

Documentation pointers:

- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/services_apply.html
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/exec.html
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_defaults.html

Answer (score 2):

That.. shouldn't work as part of a full run.  It needs a full path to the executable in the `unless` command.  Maybe you've got a path set in a global file that's part of your full runs?

Try `unless => '/usr/bin/[ -e "${logfile}" ]'`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shane that the default path is probably set in a globally scoped manifest.  You could do the same but you can't pass it as an argument, so either use stdin:

```
$ puppet apply -v --modulepath=moduleshere --noop <<EOF
Exec { path => "/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin" }
include myclass
EOF
```

or put the Exec and include lines into `example.pp` and then use `puppet apply -v ... example.pp`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use fully qualified path.

For example either:

```
exec { "sample":
  command => "/usr/bin/test",
}
```

or:

```
exec { "sample":
  path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/bin'],
  command => "test",
}
```